# Are there problems with using inheritance from the domain layer for models in the storage layer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, inheritance, separation-of-concerns

Using EF 6 code first, relatively new to separation of concerns, DI, inheritance, etc. The classes below are simplified to focus on my question.  I have an MVC Project for the presentation layer, a Class Library Project for the domain layer and a Class Library Project for SQL layer.

I designed the following model in the domain layer:

```
Public Class TaskList
    <Key> Public Overridable Property TaskListID As Integer
    Public Property TaskListOwner As String
    Public Property Tasks As New List(Of TaskItem)
End Class

Public Class TaskItem
    <Key> Public Overridable Property TaskId As Integer
    Public Property TaskName As String
    Public Property TaskDesc As String
    Public Property TaskOwner As String
End Class
```

And this model in the SQL layer using inheritance from the domain:

```
Public Class SqlTaskList
    Inherits TaskList
    <Key> Public Overrides Property TaskListID As Integer

    Function SqlToDomainTaskList() As TaskList
     ...
        Return theDomainTaskList
    End Function
End Class

Public Class SqlTaskItem
    Inherits TaskItem
    <Key> Public Overrides Property TaskId As Integer

    Function SqlToDomainTaskItem(theSqlTaskItem) As TaskItem
     ...
        Return theDomainTaskItem
    End Function
End Class
```

Will I run into problems later on coding like this?  It just seemed like using inheritance kept me from repeating myself when designing the SQL models (the real models are of course much larger), and also allows changes in the domain model to automatically propagate into the storage model.  Did I get this right, wrong, partially right?  Will I have problems later on doing it like this?

Regarding separation of concerns, wouldn't be OK for the SQL layer to be more tightly coupled with the domain since the SQL layer is always saving the domain objects?

Comment: Yes you will run into problems later.  I suggest designing to interfaces and having classes that know how to convert IWhatever to IWhateverElse.  Designing to interfaces will help you during unit testing.  Keeping your interfaces at your UI, Controller and Data layers will help you keep each layer separate.  You can probably have business objects (Interfaces) that travel up and down your layers.  Ex. The data layer knows how to serialize/deserialize objects but no other layer needs that.   Once you start going for code coverage, you will be glad you designed everything to interfaces.

Comment: I think I understand interfaces defining the 'contract', what objects can/must do & how it eases testing. My question regards property definitions only.  If I `inherit` properties I don't have to repeat them in every class using the same set of basic properties, but if I `implement` interfaces w/ properties, I have to repeat every property.  Maybe I don't properly grasp unit testing for property models but in my ex I inherit only property definitions, nothing else.  Does that make any difference in your inherit vs implement recommendation? I was trying to follow `don't repeat yourself`.

Comment: In my case, I have 10 class models that include an identical set of basic property definitions.

Comment: If you rigidly adhere to creating Plain Old Compiler Objects (POCO) then you will be fine ... until you hit a special case.  An alternative to inheritance is composition where your common properties are a POCO that is a property at each layer.  What you will probably find is that you change something in a different layer and other things holding that reference don't realize it was changed out from under them.  That's essentially the same problem with passing objects up and down your hierarchy though.  IMO interfaces can help both of those issues by restricting the writable properties.

Comment: Would I be correct saying you have to treat inherited `common` classes that only supply properties just like they were libraries, meaning you can add, but you can never take away?  And then, please confirm my other supposition; if I use an interface (which I get is safer), I will have to code each and every property in each class that implements the inheritance?  Regarding your comment about `composition`, is that saying each property that might have been inherited and was a stand alone property becomes, in `composition`, like a `sub-property`.

Comment: Kinda getting discussion-y here.  My advice is to try it, don't be afraid to fail, hopefully soon, and redirect as necessary.